# Can MSI work with EF CodeFirst?

Tags: azure, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, azure-managed-identity

I've gotten stuck on this for quite a while now, with no luck advancing it on my own.

I am trying to connect from an Azure App Service to a EF CodeFirst managed database, using an MSI token.

When I deployed the App Service using ARM I produced an Output that ensured that it created a Service Principal:

```
 {
  "principalId":"98f2c1f2-0a86-4ff1-92db-d43ec0edxxxx","
  tenantId":"e6d2d4cc-b762-486e-8894-4f5f440dxxxx",
  "type":"SystemAssigned"
 }
```

In Kudu the environment variables show that it is being installed:

```
MSI_ENDPOINT = http://127.0.0.1:41239/MSI/token/
MSI_SECRET = 7C1B16Fxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have provided in the Azure Portal a connection string as follows:

```
Data Source=nzmoebase0000bt.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=nzmoebase0001bt;Connect Timeout=300;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;
```

I've added the principal to the database as an Owner.

```
Note: I cannot do the same for the master db.
```

The token is added to the DbContext as follows:

The token is being added using:

```
    static async Task AttachAccessTokenToDbConnection(IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = dbConnection as SqlConnection;
        if (sqlConnection == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        string msiEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSI_ENDPOINT");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msiEndpoint))
        {
            return;
        }

        var msiSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSI_SECRET");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msiSecret))
        {
            return;
        }

        // To get around:
        // "Cannot set the AccessToken property if 'UserID', 'UID', 'Password', or 'PWD' has been specified in connection string."
        var terms = new[] {"UserID","Password","PWD=","UID=" };
        string connectionString = dbConnection.ConnectionString;

        foreach (var term in terms)
        {
            if (connectionString.Contains(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        string accessToken = await AppCoreDbContextMSITokenFactory.GetAzureSqlResourceTokenAsync();
        sqlConnection.AccessToken = accessToken;
    }
```

With tracing on, the token is:

```
 .eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI....
```

Which decoded using jwt.io gave:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "FSimuFrFNoC0sJXGmv13nNZceDc",
  "kid": "FSimuFrFNoC0sJXGmv13nNZceDc"
}.{
  "aud": "https://database.windows.net/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/e6d2d4cc-b762-486e-8894-4f5f440dxxxx/",
  "iat": 1522783025,
  "nbf": 1522783025,
  "exp": 1522786925,
  "aio": "Y2NgYPjNdyJd9zrzpLavJSEzNIuPAAA=",
  "appid": "d1057cea-461b-4946-89a9-d76439c2xxxx",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "e_exp": 262800,
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/e6d2d4cc-b762-486e-8894-4f5f440dxxxx/",
  "oid": "98f2c1f2-0a86-4ff1-92db-d43ec0edxxxx",
  "sub": "98f2c1f2-0a86-4ff1-92db-d43ec0edxxxx",
  "tid": "e6d2d4cc-b762-486e-8894-4f5f440dxxxx",
  "uti": "59bqKWiSL0Gf0bTCI0AAAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}.[Signature]
```

I Added `Persist Security Info = True` as per several recommendations on the net, but that did nothing detectable.

```
Data Source=nzmoebase0000bt.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=nzmoebase0001bt;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Persist Security Info = True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

The error I am getting is:

```
[InvalidOperationException: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.]
```

Has anyone gotten a connection to a database, using CodeFirst, with Migrations, and MSI? At this point, after several weeks of being really stuck, I'm starting to wonder if it is possible.

Thanks for any help -- even if just proof that it can work, for starters.

Comment: Has this been answered?  A colleague of mine is having the exact same issue.

Comment: anyone find a solution for this?  I'm bumping into this ....

Comment: I am also trying to connect to SQL server database using MSI + code first approach(EntityFrameworkCore6). I have tried generating the token using the interceptor(Azure.Identity) as well as AzureServiceTokenProvider(AppAuthentication). I am getting errors while connecting to the database from my local machine.

My database is not on the local. But, I am trying to connect it from Visual Studio. But, it gives me errors like below:
Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information.  
does anyone have solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge, no. A major stumbling block to a project that had to fall back to unsecure Username/password loaded connection strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the access token on the sql connection like that:

1. Install the `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` nuget package
2. set up your context class like that:

   ```
   public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
   {
       public MyDatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<MyDatabaseContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
           // Get the db connection
           var connection = (SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();

           // Add the access token
           connection.AccessToken = new AzureServiceTokenProvider()
               .GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/")
               .ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
       }

       public DbSet<MyTable> MyTable { get; set; }
   }
   ```