# How to run EF6 code-first migrations from Visual Studio with Managed Identity

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I have a system managed identity created and working from both Azure and debugging within Visual Studio 2019 via Azure Service Authentication, however when I run `Update-Database` from the Package Manager Console I am unable to apply the code-first migrations with the following exception.

As I said it works everywhere except for migrations, which makes me think that Powershell is not able to locate the dll's. I have tried running the command from the build folder of the project with the same exception being thrown.

- EntityFramework 6.2
- Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication 1.5.0

Is there some other configuration that needs to be done?

````
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Failed to instantiate an authentication provider with type 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.SqlAppAuthenticationProvider, Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication' for 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.SqlAppAuthenticationProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication'.
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
       at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager..ctor(SqlAuthenticationProviderConfigurationSection configSection)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager..ctor(SqlAuthenticationProviderConfigurationSection configSection)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
    The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager' threw an exception.
    ```
````

Comment: Can you update these nuget packages and check if the error still persists?

Comment: Same result @HarshitaSingh-MSFT after updating to EF 6.4.4 & Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication 1.6.0. Is there an option (like efcore) for creating a design-time context where I can obtain the auth token manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can MSI work with EF CodeFirst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054491/can-msi-work-with-ef-codefirst)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't. We resorted to running the migrations with a separate (sa) account, using a console application.

Comment: We could get a new project to work but the existing one I've inherited won't work, maybe due to the separation of projects. I went with a console app as well, using a managed identity.